# Crypting in Nodejs with hybrid-rsa-stream and decrypting in C# with OpenSSL

Tags: c#, php, node.js, encryption, openssl

Hy,
I'm trying to encrypt a file in node and decrypt it in C#. 
To encrypt the the file I use Hybrid-rsa-stream that internally uses rsa-stream, And then I use ManagedOpenSSL to decrypt the file.
this is my Node code

```
var enc = rsa.encrypt(pubkey);
var out = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(localPath, "crypt-" + fileName), {flags: 'w'});
var input = fs.createReadStream(path.join(localPath, fileName));
input.pipe(enc).pipe(out);
```

Since I'm using a 1024 bit key, the modulus length should be 128 bytes, I tried setting different modulus length as a param to rsa.encrypt but nothing changed decypting it.
This is my c# code

```
 CryptoKey cryptoKey = CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(_privateKey, null);
 RSA _rsa = cryptoKey.GetRSA();
 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(toDecrypt, FileMode.Open));
 List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
 while (br.BaseStream.Position != br.BaseStream.Length)
 {
     result.AddRange(_rsa.PrivateDecrypt(br.ReadBytes(_rsa.Size), RSA.Padding.None));
 }
```

But when I try to decrypt the file I get an error

> error:04065084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data too large for modulus

I don't think it has nothing to deal with the padding setting, I tried changing it but nothing changed.

The private key has a nelinw character at the end(\n), I tried removing it but nothing changed,

**EDIT:** I noticed that cripting blocks of rsa.size - 1 dosn't throw any error, and the file gets written, but It's damaged and I can't open it

**EDIT 2:** The problem seems to be the hybrid-rsa-stream, wich dosn't crypt the blocks of bytes with the public key, but crypts all the file with AES-256-CBC and a random key that he generates, then at the end of the operation, hybrid-rsa-stream adds the random generated key crypted with the public key. how can I "revert" this operations in c#?

Comment: How long is your data? Have you tried encrypting short data smaller than 74 bytes? I mean it's exactly what the error message says.

Comment: Yes, same problem, can I ask you way 74 bytes? the modulus should be 128 bytes, why did you suggest 74?

Comment: There are different padding options for RSA. I think OAEP needs at least 54 bytes to work, PKCS#1 1.5 needs at least 11 bytes. I'm not sure which one is used or whether one is used at all.

Comment: I tried them all just to be sure, but all of them gave me the same error, diging into rsa-stream code seems that it applies no padding, so I think that padding.None is the right one...